# SolaimanLipi font is breaking the connected word in iReport exporting PDF

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, export-to-pdf

I am using iReport 5.6.0 version. I am trying to work with custom font, in my case SolaimanLipi.ttf. It works perfectly in internal view. But when I export to PDF file then it is breaking with the combined letter (for my case: Bengali). I have googled for it and try some but no luck.

My attempts are as follows.

**When adding TTF font:**

[image]

**In iReport view:**

[image]

**In exported PDF - broken:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Support for Indic scripts in PDF has been introduced in JasperReports 6.2.0, see [the changelog](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/blob/jr-6-2-0/jasperreports/changes.txt).

You will not be able to benefit from that with iReport 5.6.0.  I suggest downloading the latest Jaspersoft Studio release from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperstudio/files/).

Comment: can you add the process please?